# Filter out the word and its value from a file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

i have a  file  with content like below: filename:input..txt

```
   <autoCommit=false, currentThread=Thread[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)',5,Pooled Threads],connectTime=102,lastUser=null,currentError=null,currentErrorTimestamp=null,JDBC4Runtime=true,supportStatementPoolable=true,needRestoreClientInfo=false,defaultClientInfo={},supportIsValid=true>
    > <autoCommit=false,enabled=true,isXA=false,isJTS=false,vendorID=100,connUsed=false,doInit=false,'null',destroyed=false,poolname=ApplicationDB,appname=null,moduleName=null,connectTime=98,**dirtyIsolationLevel=false,initialIsolationLevel=2,infected=false,lastSuccessfulConnectionUse=1475188184480,secondsToTrustAnIdlePoolConnection=0,currentUser=java.lang.Exception
```

i want to grep all patterns with connectTime=  with its value associated.

```
for example from above file the o/p will be:
connectTime=102
connectTime=98
```

Tried

```
 egrep -r 'connectTime='  input.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*\(connectTime=[0-9]*\).*/\1/' input.txt
connectTime=102
connectTime=98
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do that:

```
egrep -o "connectTime=[0-9]+" input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` solution: This will poll through all the field per line in the file and if any filed contains connectTime then print that field.

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ "connectTime") print $i}' inputfile
connectTime=102
connectTime=98
```

Or if you want to be strict about the values of connectTime to be a digit then :

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i ~ "connectTime=[[:digit:]][^[:alpha:]]") print $i}}' inputfile
```

or `grep`:

```
    grep -oP 'connectTime=[0-9]+' inputfile
    connectTime=102
    connectTime=98
```

or this may break easily. This will only work if `connecTime=somenumber` is followed by a `comma` sign. which is present in provided data. This will print anything after connectTime.

```
grep -oP 'connectTime.*?(?=,)' inputfile
connectTime=102
connectTime=98
```

If you want to make it strict for the case in which only numbers are followed by connectTime then

```
grep -oP 'connectTime.[0-9]*?(?=,)' inputfile
```